# Adding a value to a list thats named the same as another one with an extra letter or a sliced off letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Title may be confusing, but what i'm trying to do is, Adding Something to a list, and that list, is named the same as that Somethings list, but with an extra letter sliced off. I could do this for each list, but i am working with alot of lists and i can not do this for each list. Here is something that would help explain:

```
lst1 = ['something', 'another_thing']
lst = []
another_list1 = ['thing', 'item']
another_list = []
all_lists = [list1, another_list1]
for lsst in all_lists:
    corresponding_list = lsst - lsst[-1]   #i know this wont work, but i dont know what to do here.
    for item in lsst:
        corresponding_list.append(item)
        corresponding_list.append(item + "!")
```

So the Expected Value in The corresponding list ( The lists name missing the last letter/number at the end) Is The original value, And the original Value + "!". 
So basically how to make a for loop, that would add something that belongs to a list, to another list, and that another list is named the same but with an extra letter at the end or missing a letter at the end.
Expected output, in the lst to be ['something', 'something!', 'another_ thing', 'another_thing!']

Comment: You're right that I did not understand. Can you give us the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to slice variable names.
You cannot do that.
What you can do is use a dictionary:

```
mylists = {'list1':['foo', 'ba'],\
           'list' :[]\
           ...
          } 
listname = 'list1'
mylist[listname]
mylist[listname[:-1]]
```

Comment: But how can i use this with a for loop? i am using tons of lists. sorry if this comment makes no sense, im still a starter.

Comment: In that case make a dictionary only for the lists whose names end in `1`. Then research how to loop over the keys in a dictionary.